# angular typescript custom namespace

Tags: angular, typescript

I am testing custom namespace to make a nicer `import`:

All the components are added into a folder `app\components\`

[image]

file `conponents.module.ts`:

```
...
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ServicesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    ...
  ],
  exports:[
    MessagesComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

added the `paths` to `tsconfig.ts`:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths":{
          "@beewest/components/*" : ["app/components/*"]
        },
```

`components.module.ts` failed to compile with the error `ERROR in src/app/components/components.module.ts(11,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@beewest/components'.` if the path is modified to:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '@beewest/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
```

Visual Studio Code shows no error but `ng serve` returns `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@beewest/components/dashboard/dashboard.component'`.

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: That's known as barrelling. You'll need to create an `index.ts` file that exports everything. Take a look at http://www.riptutorial.com/angular2/example/32152/using-barrel for more information

Comment: just want to wrap under custom namespace as suggested in https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `paths` is updated after restarting `ng serve`.

`@beewest/...` is  resolved to `app/...` based on the `paths` configured:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '@beewest/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
```

To remove `.../dashboard/dashboard.component`, typescript's [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) requires file `index.ts` added to folder `app/components` with `export` lines:

```
export {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
```

Nicer import lines:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '@beewest/components';
```